# switching between http and https - how to inform google

Tags: http, https

My site is deployed on amazon aws and I have two listeners on the load balancer.

One for http and one for https.

Google links to the http url, however I'd like it to link to the https listener as I am about to disable the http listener on port 80.

Can anyone recommend an approach which will result in the smoothest transition from the perspective of people finding my site through google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a redirect. This means, that for now, you can't turn of the listener on http, but need to put the permanent redirect there instead. When google next checks, it'll spot the permanent redirect, drop the old link and create the new.

You could try submitting a new site map, but you'd lose any ranking your old links had gained as they would all appear as new links, plus there's no telling how long it would take Google to use the site map.

And there's also Bing and Yahoo and other search engines. Probably not as common, but best to hits a solution that gets them all.

Redirect using .htaccess - google it or reply here if you're stuck and I'll add to the answer